# Twitter REST APIで特定の文字で投稿に失敗する

Tags: twitter

Twitter連携を行い、自動投稿を行うアプリを開発しています。

アプリ自体は完成したのですが、
Twitter REST API で特定の文字を含む文言を投稿しようとすると、

```
"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."
```

というエラーとなってしまいます。
特定文字が含まれない文章の場合はエラーにならず、正常に投稿されます。

自作アプリが異常なのかと思い、Twitterオフィシャルのtwurlを利用して投稿してみても、やはり同様のエラーとなります。

今のところ、NGとなっている単語は`や^などです。

具体的にエラーになるtwurlの実行時のコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
twurl -t -X POST -d 'status=(*´∀`)♪(o)v( ＾∀＾)( ＾∀＾)(´∇｀)' /1.1/statuses/update.json
```

Twitterのオフィシャルドキュメントを読んでも特に文字種制限については触れられていませんし、投稿時のPOSTをトレースすると正常にURLエンコードされて送信されているように見えます。
TwitterのWebから上記文言を投稿すると正常に投稿できるので、NG文言ではないとは思います。
投稿文字列をUTF-8の\u28\u2A ... のように数値参照にするなどいろいろ試してみたものの、うまくいきませんでした。

こちら、上記のような特殊文字でも正常に投稿される方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

■■■追記■■■

ご質問いただいたので、再現環境について補足いたします。

■自作アプリ
・開発環境：Untiy2018.1.5f
・開発言語：C#
・再現環境：UnityEditor上、Windows、iPhone、Androidいずれの環境でも再現します
・投稿コード抜粋（おおよその流れで実際のコードとは異なります）

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("status", "(*´∀`)♪(o)v( ＾∀＾)( ＾∀＾)(´∇｀)");
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", form);
    request.SetRequestHeader("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", Oauth.GenerateHeaderWithAccessToken("/1.1/statuses/update.json"));
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
```

■twurl
・再現環境：CentOS release 6.6 (Final)、ruby 2.2.0p0、twurl 0.9.3
・LANG環境変数：ja_JP.UTF-8
・再現コード（最初の投稿の記載の通りです）

```
    twurl -t -X POST -d 'status=(*´∀`)♪(o)v( ＾∀＾)( ＾∀＾)(´∇｀)' /1.1/statuses/update.json
```

twurlでも再現するので、自作アプリの再現環境・コードについては不要かと思っておりました。
失礼いたしました。

他にも必要な情報がございましたらご指摘ください。

Comment: なお、twurlはtwitterオフィシャルのTwitter連携CLIクライアントで、実装はrubyとなっており、 https://github.com/twitter/twurl こちらで公開されております。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/148847

Comment: 情報の追記ありがとうございました。一部特定の文字が含まれる場合、標準的な方法で作成されたOAuth用の`Authorization`ヘッダーをTwitter REST API側が正しいものとして認識出来ていないと言う状態のようです。C#/Ruby側に共通のバグがある(OAuth仕様は解釈が難しいので、可能性は十分あり得ます)のか、Twitter REST API側の問題(同じ理由でこちらも十分あり得ます)なのかはわかりません。他のOAuthライブラリを使うTwitterクライアントで同じ文字列が送れるかなど試してみると、切り分けができるかもしれません。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。OAuthのヘッダーが異常になっているということなのは間違いないようですので、OAuthの仕様からきちんと調べてみようと思います。